# How to split column headers and detail across two or more pages

Tags: jasper-reports, break

We are building a dynamic report designer that is based on *JasperReports*.  For the most part, we use PDF as the default output.

We are facing a serious problem where, for example, if a user selects eight columns in a report, it may be that the only way to print the report is so that the first 4 columns detail and headers show on the first page and the last 4 column detail and headers show on a second page.

It looks like column breaks are the way to do this and I've been trying them in Jasper Reports, but with no luck.  Below I've added the detail band in a jrxml file where I'm trying to use the break element to break to a new page after the third column.  I'm trying to use a printWhenExpression on the column break to break before the fourth column.

Note that while this test case is small and really doesn't need a break other reports that are being created have 20+ columns that need to be spread across 3 or more pages.

```html
 <detail>
  <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="24" y="1" width="100" height="15" uuid="4bb1d713-2c34-42e9-aeb4-63aa41d10060"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{L_BUILDING_CODE}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="140" y="1" width="100" height="15" uuid="9d55a9e3-fa9f-497b-b744-dd853ac21a4a"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{L_BUILDING_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="250" y="1" width="100" height="15" uuid="e70b4bc4-a8a7-4e97-abdc-e58346daa002"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{L_CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <break type="Column">
    <reportElement key="" x="0" y="1" width="250" height="1" uuid="3bf6f2c0-a0d6-43dd-9d3f-ddd1e46d5fc7" >
     <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_NUMBER}.intValue() == 4]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
   </break>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="600" y="1" width="100" height="15" uuid="19cb12e8-6474-4776-a9fa-2c7d34e69573"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{L_STATE_PROVINCE}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>
```

Can someone show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: I had same issue printed in landscape.You can try.

Comment: When you say columns are you saying like the Band "Columns Header" and "Column Footer". Because column breaks are based upon that.